# how to verify whether a site has mobile compliant pages

Tags: web, mobile-website

Many of the web sites have mobile compliant pages for mobile browsers. We have a few URLs and we want to know whether the pages pointed to by these URLs have mobile compliant pages. So opened all these URLs in a browser on a mobile and checked whether the browser is loading a huge page or small mobile friendly page. Is this the correct way of checking or are there better ways of doing it?

Answer (score -1):

Use any smartphone simulators for iphone http://www.testiphone.com/

Comment: When I entered www.amazon.com, it is loading the full page, not the mobile compatible page. So this is not useful.